# Segmentation fault while returning pointer

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have begin learning pointers in C.

When I try to return pointer in a function, I'm getting `segmentation fault` error.

Here is the code :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int *sum(int *, int *);

int main(void)
{
    int a, b;
    int *ans = NULL;
    printf("Enter number a : ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Enter number b : ");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    ans = sum(&a, &b);
    printf("Sum = %d", *ans); 

    return 0;   
}

int *sum(int *p, int *q)
{
    int *result = NULL;
    *result = *p + *q;
    return (result);
}
```

And the output :

```
Enter number a : 10
Enter number b : 20
Segmentation fault
```

Segmentation fault occurs in `sum` function, when `result` is declared as pointer. However, I am unable to figure out the reason for the same. Any help regarding this is really appreciable.

Comment: Dereferencing a null pointer is not legal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are initing a pointer to `NULL` and then you are deferencing it: it is [Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Change `sum` function to

```
int *sum(int *p, int *q)
{
    int *result = malloc(sizeof(int));

    // check if malloc returned a valid pointer before to dereference it
    if (result != NULL)
    {
        *result = *p + *q;
    }

    return (result);
}
```

and add a [free](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) call to free the allocated memory.

```
    // check if sum function allocate the pointer before to dereference it
    if (ans != NULL)
    {
       printf("Sum = %d", *ans); 
    }

    free(ans);

    return 0;   
}
```

You could also avoid to use pointer to return value:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int sum(int *, int *);

int main(void)
{
    int a, b;
    int ans;
    printf("Enter number a : ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Enter number b : ");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    ans = sum(&a, &b);
    printf("Sum = %d\n", ans); 

    return 0;   
}

int sum(int *p, int *q)
{
    int result = *p + *q;
    return (result);
}
```

The `sum` function could also be like:

```
int sum (int *p, int *q)
{
    return (*p + *q);
}
```

**EDIT**

As @JonathanLeffler wrote in his answer you can do also:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void sum(int *, int *, int *);

int main(void)
{
    int a, b;
    int ans;
    printf("Enter number a : ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Enter number b : ");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    sum(&ans, &a, &b);
    printf("Sum = %d\n", ans);

    return 0;
}

void sum(int *result, int *p, int *q)
{
    *result = *p + *q;
}
```

Comment: And there's really no benefit to passing the arguments as pointers, so you could use `static inline int sum(int p, int q) { return p + q; }` if you wanted to, though you'd probably want to place that above where it is used.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, sure, but OP wrote: _I have begin learning pointers in C_

Comment: And one of the lessons to learn about pointers is when to use them and when not to use them.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful. Using malloc solves this issue.  
I did came up with alternatives, however I wanted to implement _function returning a pointer_ specifically. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Allocate memory before trying to store anything, and check the return of `malloc()`

```
int *result = NULL;
result = malloc(sizeof(*result));
if(result != NULL)
    *result = *p + *q;
else
    printf("malloc returned error");
```

Also, check the return of the function in `main()` and exit accordingly.

```
int main(void)
{
    .
    .
    .
    ans = sum(&a, &b);
    if(ans == NULL)
        return 0;

    printf("Sum = %d\n", ans);
    free(ans);    //free the memory then
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not: `int *result = malloc(sizeof(*result));`?  And it might be an idea to use `if (result != NULL) *result = *p + *q;`.  There's also no good reason to pass the arguments by pointer rather than just by value.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler. Thanks. Added the return value check.

Comment: @M.M, All set now. :)

Answer (score 2):

A third alternative is to declare `ans` as a normal `int` variable in the `main` function and pass a pointer to it to the `sum` function, like you do with the other two arguments. This is actually emulating *call by reference*.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to add code to my answer based on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
#include<stdio.h>

int *sum(int *, int *);

int main(void)
{
    int a, b;
    printf("Enter number a : ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Enter number b : ");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    int* ans = sum(&a, &b);
    printf("Sum = %d", *ans); 

    return 0;   
}

int *sum(int *p, int *q)
{
    int plus = *p + *q;
    int *ans = &plus;
    return ans;
}
```

Store the Sum in a Different variable `plus` and create a pointer `*ans` that points to that variable `plus` and return the pointer variable `ans` that holds the address of `plus`